# How can I add 3D to my raphael.js application? Can I combine raphael.js with webgl?

Tags: raphael, webgl

I have coded a 2D visualization using raphael.js but now I need to add some 3D features to this visualization. Is there a way I can use 3D libraries in my rapahel application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As raphael objects are DOM elements, depending on where your need you 3D items, you could use [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) which can use WebGL to render on to a canvas element. Obviously you sould need to consider the stacking order because the canvas would need to be beneath your raphael content to avoid obscuring it.